# Можно ли использовать Laravel Eloquent методы в цикле?

Tags: php, laravel

В документации Laravel Eloquent есть  методы например `Model::UpdateOrCreate()`, но нету примеров, как использовать эти методы для множества строк, в [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594076/seed-multiple-rows-at-once-laravel-5)  нашел пример, где предлагается  для множества строк использовать цикл:

```
foreach($users as $user){
    User::create($user);
}
```

Насколько целесообразно использовать query запрос в цикле ?

Может ли быть, что ларавел  использует асинхронные технологии, например, queue или другие возможности которые разрешают использовать такие запросы внутри цикла ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На гитхабе обсуждали это: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1295

Следующий код создает столько запросов сколько итераций.

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    User::create($user);
}
```

Вот что писал про это автор Laravel:

> It would be relatively easy to do this; however, events would not be
>   fired. The only thing it would be buying you is the timestamp
>   insertion.

Перевод:  это было бы относительно легко сделать; однако события не будут запущены. Это только поможет вставлять timestamp автоматически.

и это:

> Honestly just use the query builder for this. Will be much more
>   efficient and makes more sense.

Перевод: Честно говоря, просто используйте построитель запросов для этого. Будет намного эффективнее и иметь больше смысла.

---

Один из пользователей предложил вариант ниже, но он тоже не генерирует события:

```
abstract class Model extends BaseModel
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public static function table()
    {
        return with(new static)->table;
    }

    /**
     * Insert each item as a row. Does not generate events.
     *
     * @param  array  $items
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function insertAll(array $items)
    {
        $now = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
        $items = collect($items)->map(function (array $data) use ($now) {
            return $this->timestamps ? array_merge([
                'created_at' => $now,
                'updated_at' => $now,
            ], $data) : $data;
        })->all();

        return \DB::table(static::table())->insert($items);
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
Administrator::insertAll([
    ['name' => 'Zane'],
    ['name' => 'Rob'],
]);
```

[Источник кода](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1295#issuecomment-193025045)